# Log4j Vulnerability impact on Cloud SDK project

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

We have some use cases which leverage Cloud SDK project template for Java. Now they are already running on SAP BTP, Cloud Foundry environment. By default, it uses **logback** and we did not change it.

When getting dependencies with maven command **mvn dependency:tree** in cloud sdk project, I can see **log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.14.1** and **log4j-api:jar:2.14.1** is used by SAP Spring xsuaa library and spring-boot-starter-logging.

```
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.14.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.14.1:compile

[INFO] +- com.sap.cloud.security.xsuaa:xsuaa-spring-boot-starter:jar:2.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sap.cloud.security.xsuaa:spring-xsuaa:jar:2.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.14.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.14.1:compile
```

According the [Spring official documentation][1]. Only **log4j-core** is affected. The **log4j-to-slf4j** and **log4j-api** jars that we include in **spring-boot-starter-logging** cannot be exploited on their own. From my perspective, there should be no impact on Cloud SDK project with libraries originally included.

Could you give some comments?

Answer (score 4):

This writeup of the SLF4J developers describes their situation quite well: http://slf4j.org/log4shell.html

> The SLF4J API is just an API which lets message data go through.

This means it all depends on the actual logging implementation that you use.
The SDK modules do not provide or expect any logging implementation.

In our CF Archetypes we use `slf4j-simple` for test cases and `logback` for productive logging, however this can be changed by the consumer of the archetype.

On Neo the runtime provides an implementation, so that the archetype does not provide any implementation.